# Value comparisons not working as expected

Tags: php

Im trying to show different colours depending on the two values.

First of all if the values are equal then show green which works fine

```
  <?php if (miletofurlong($pasthorse['distance']) == $todaysdistance)
    {
      $Horsedist = "<b><span style='color:#ff4500 '>". miletofurlong($pasthorse['distance'])."f</span></b>";
    } ?>
```

Now what I'm trying to do is if `miletofurlong($pasthorse['distance'])` is not equal to but is still between ($todaysdistance + 1) and ($todaysdistance + 1) then highlight it blue.

I have ran the following code but it seems to highlight everything and I'm unsure why

```
if (miletofurlong($pasthorse['distance']) == $todaysdistance)
    {
    $Horsedist = "<b><span style='color:#ff4500 '>". miletofurlong($pasthorse['distance'])."f</span></b>";
    }
    elseif (miletofurlong($pasthorse['distance']) !== $todaysdistance and miletofurlong($pasthorse['distance']) <= ($todaysdistance + 1) or miletofurlong($pasthorse['distance']) !== $todaysdistance and miletofurlong($pasthorse['distance']) >= ($todaysdistance - 1)  )
    {
    $Horsedist = "<b><span style='color:blue'>". miletofurlong($pasthorse['distance'])."f</span></b>". ($todaysdistance + 1). "and" . ($todaysdistance - 1);
    }
    else
    {
    $Horsedist = miletofurlong($pasthorse['distance'])."f" ;
    }
```

[image: screenshot of the output]

Comment: Are you checking this part properly? *"but is still between ($todaysdistance + 1) and ($todaysdistance + 1) "* How can something be between two numbers that are the same?

Comment: May be this can help you in place of second condition elseif ((miletofurlong($pasthorse['distance']) !== $todaysdistance && miletofurlong($pasthorse['distance']) <= ($todaysdistance + 1)) || ( miletofurlong($pasthorse['distance']) !== $todaysdistance && miletofurlong($pasthorse['distance']) >= ($todaysdistance - 1)) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing parenthesis, and your if case is a bit messy. Let's first use a variable and declare your $pasthorse inside.

```
$distance = miletofurlong($ pasthorse['distance']);
if ($distance == $todaysdistance)
    $Horsedist = "<b><span style='color:#ff4500 '>". $distance ."f</span></b>";
else if ($distance <= ($todaysdistance + 1) and $distance >= ($todaysdistance - 1)  )
    $Horsedist = "<b><span style='color:blue'>". $distance . "f</span></b>"  ($todaysdistance + 1). "and" . ($todaysdistance - 1);
else
    $Horsedist = $distance ."f" ;
```

There, it should work way better, and it's more readable.